# Optional Extra Info in golang Model

Tags: go, backend, go-gorm

I implemented three models for the backend in golang
Category, product and document
Models are defined as follows

```golang
type Category struct {
  ID uint
  Title string
  Products []*Product
}

type Product struct {
  ID uint
  Name string
  CategoryID uint
  Documents []*Document
}

type Document struct {
  ID uint
  Title string
  MimeType string
  Url string
  ProductID uint
}
```

There are different categories, what I want is to receive information other than what is in the document for certain categories. For example, when the category is wall instance, the size and Structure of the wall should also be taken.
It exists in some categories and each of them should receive additional information other than what is in the document by default.
My question is, how can I implement this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using generics:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Wall struct {
    Size      int
    Structure string
}

type Category[Spec any] struct {
    ID       uint
    Title    string
    Products []*Product[Spec]
}

func (s Category[Spec]) Dump() {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n(", s)
    for id := range s.Products {
        s.Products[id].Dump()
    }
}

type Product[Spec any] struct {
    ID         uint
    Name       string
    CategoryID uint
    Documents  []*Document[Spec]
}

func (p Product[Spec]) Dump() {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n(", p)
    for id := range p.Documents {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n(", p.Documents[id])
    }
}

type Document[Spec any] struct {
    Spec      Spec
    ID        uint
    Title     string
    MimeType  string
    Url       string
    ProductID uint
}

func main() {
    wall := Category[Wall]{
        ID:    1,
        Title: "a",
        Products: []*Product[Wall]{{
            ID:         1,
            Name:       "b",
            CategoryID: 1,
            Documents: []*Document[Wall]{{
                Spec: Wall{
                    Size:      12,
                    Structure: "c",
                },
                ID:        1,
                Title:     "d",
                MimeType:  "e",
                Url:       "https://f.com",
                ProductID: 1,
            }},
        }},
    }
    wall.Dump()
}
```

output:

```
{ID:1 Title:a Products:[0xc00007c040]}
({ID:1 Name:b CategoryID:1 Documents:[0xc000066180]}
(&{Spec:{Size:12 Structure:c} ID:1 Title:d MimeType:e Url:https://f.com ProductID:1}
```